# How can I access Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition? (No Shortcut)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2015 from DreamSpark. I downloaded the iso file and ran it, starting the installation. From there, it just basically installed itself. Afterward, the program didn't launch because I had to restart my computer. Upon starting Windows back up, there was no icon on the desktop, there was no shortcut in my tool bar at the bottom of the screen.

Perplexed as to why this wasn't part of the installation, I checked the folder I installed it to, which was the one that it defaulted to. Navigated to C://ProgramFiles(x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE. From there I searched through the executable files and found nothing that looked like a way to open the browser. All I can find are some peripheral features like the Web functionality, the Graphical interface, but nothing to get to the C++ coding interface. Any suggestions? Am I looking in the wrong folder or something?

Comment: Something went wrong with the installation; what I can't tell. Look for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Comment: It's not in the "start menu"? What happens if you search for "Visual Studio" in the start menu/screen?

Comment: @JVene Thanks. I didn't know what the executable was supposed to be called to open it. I found it and it opens up just fine. I tried googling before hand to see what the executable itself is called, but I didn't have any luck.